# Non-pip-installable python modules on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am trying to deploy a Django Web-App that, amongst other, implements the IfcOpenShell Python module (http://ifcopenshell.org/python
).

Unfortunately, this module is not available through pip install. To use it locally, I just download the files and paste them in my python environment site-packages folder.

When I deploy this App on Heroku the IfcOpenShell module is missing of course. Is there a possibility to add it manually to Heroku somehow?

Answer (score 1):

We use ifcopenshell in our heroku apps. We simply dump ifcopenshell folder into our python app root folder.

Comment: Yeah that's how I did it in the end too :)